# Electron: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'receive') | ipc cannot receive args I sent through HTML iframe

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ipc

I am trying to send lightmode and language data through ipcMain to ipcRenderer through my preload script:

`Preload.js:`

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

const ipc = {
  render: {
    send: ["mainMenuUpdate"],
    receive: ["windowStats"],
  },
};

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("ipcRender", {
  // From render to main.
  send: (channel, args) => {
    let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
      ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
    }
  },
  // From main to render.
  receive: (channel, args) => {
    let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
      ipcRenderer.on(channel, args);
    }
  },
});
```

I send the data like this:

`mainMenu.js:`

```
window.ipcRender.send('mainMenuUpdate', {
          // windowSkin and currentLanguage are both coming from the previous window update 
          // and are an object with hexvalues and string respectively. Doesn't matter in this 
          // case
          currentSkin: windowSkin,
          currentLanguage,
   })
```

Note that this has been working for all other windows I have updated but not this one.

I recieve this no problem in `main.js` as follows:

```
ipcMain.on('mainMenuUpdate', (event, args) => {
  console.log(args);
  // outputs correcly
  mainWindow.webContents.send("windowStats", args);
});
```

and then sends it away through `windowStats` to `myPage.js`:

```
let currentLanguage;
let windowSkin;

window.ipcRender.receive("windowStats", (event, windowArgs) => {
     console.log(windowArgs);
     // does not output anything because of double error
      windowSkin = windowArgs.currentSkin;
      currentLanguage = windowArgs.currentLanguage;
      updateColors(windowArgs.currentSkin);
       langUpdate(currentLanguage);
   });
```

I get a log when sending it from `mainMenu.js`, I get the same log when received in `main.js`, just before I send it with `mainWindow.webcontents.send(//...)` but no log because of the error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of  undefined (reading
> 'receive') at myPage.js:18:18 (anonymous @ myPage.js:18)

I get this two times, exactly the same error if that would help.
I have also tried to load in the new html file both before and after I send it through IPC.

The `myPage.html` looks as follows:

```
<body>
    <main class="main-container">
        <section class="left-column">
            <div class="my-library-container">
                <div class="left-column-btns myLibrary-btn" data-translation-key data-string="myPage:myLibrary-btn">??MY
                    LIBRARY
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="collections-container">
                <div class="left-column-btns collections-btn" data-translation-key data-string="myPage:collections-btn">
                    ??COLLECTIONS</div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="main-column">
            <iframe class="main-screen" src="../myPage/myLibrary.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </section>
        <section class="right-column"></section>
    </main>

    <script defer src="../../assets/js/myPage/myPage.js"></script>
    <script defer src="../../constants/colors.js"></script>
    <script defer src="../../constants/languages.js"></script>
</body>
```

which I show inside an `iframe` like this:

```
<body>
    <main class="main-container">
        <iframe class="main-window" src="myPage/myPage.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </main>

    <script defer src="../assets/js/mainMenu.js"></script>
    <script defer src="../constants/colors.js"></script>
    <script defer src="../constants/languages.js"></script>
</body>
```

What may or may not contribute to the problem is that it seems like the javascript is loaded before the HTML even when JS file is deferred.

`myPage.js` ex.

```
const myLibraryBtn = document.querySelector('.myLibrary-btn')

myLibraryBtn.classList.add('activated')
```

and get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properies of null (reading
> 'classList') at ...

I will happily elaborate and extend this question because I have no idea what I even should look for and where.

---

UPDATE:
As I've been doing excessive testing I have concluded that I can't get anything through the ipc (main --> renderer) while the renderer is an `iframe`. I can put in a button to update the window normally without `iframe`, even though I still get a

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'receive') at myPage.js....

error. But it doesn't seem to interfere with my `updateColors()` and `langUpdate()` functions which show the HTML correctly. So the main problem is that I am not able to send anything through `mainMenuUpdate` channel and get anything but two errors as mentioned above while showing `myPage.html` inside an `iframe`. So I still get the error on both occations, while two times when `console.log()` does not work and one time when using a button instead of an `iframe` which gives one error of such and the `console.log()` with args for both `updateColor()` and `langUpdate()` functions.

Comment: Where are you putting the `script` tag in your HTML? It should be placed at the bottom of the `body` tag to ensure all elements are loaded first.

Comment: @Spectric I have indeed placed them absolute last in the body tag, with and without `defer` which should make no difference in this case.

Comment: I don't think we have all the information needed to provide an answer. Where are the "log(s)" you refer to? Are they `console.log(...)` statements which have been removed? Can you place them back into your question code for clarification? You also mention "I have also tried to load in the new html file both before and after I send it through IPC". What is the **new** html file? Lastly, your second error message is because you have no elements within your html file containing the class `myLibrary-btn`. Thus, `const myLibraryBtn = null;` and `classList` can't read a `null`.

Comment: @midnight-coding I have now updated the code with `console.log(...)` and the full `body` of the `myPage.html` which is the document I am loading in. `myLibrary-btn` is a class of one of my `<div></div>`'s which, for reference, worked before I transferred the code over to a new HTML file, which currently is the `myPage.html`. It is copy pasted because I instead show it inside an `iframe`.

Comment: As iFrames have their own **document** as stated in [`<iframe>`: The Inline Frame element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), the usual Electron IPC methods won't work. Electron discusses [`<webview>`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/webview-tag) in their API docs but discourages its use. iFrame, [BrowserView](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-view), “or an architecture that avoids embedded content" is their recommendation. We may need to look at iFrame communication using `ipcRender.postMessage(channel, message, [transfer]);`

Comment: @midnight-coding wow, so it works practically the same as IPC but now for coms between parent and `iframe`? I have never read about it before. I'll then try to post an answer with what you mentioned here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @midnight-coding mentioned about `ipcRender.postMessage(channel, message, [transfer]);` as an alternative to IPC which cannot be used to send data `parent --> iframe`; I decided to go with what I found from [Mozilla webDocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) and [this 3 min YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9nFBZ-MiuQ).

`mainMenu.js:` (renderer)

```
// iframe \/
const mainWindow = document.querySelector('.main-window');

mainWindow.contentWindow.postMessage({
          channel: 'mainMenuUpdate',
          currentSkin: windowSkin,
          currentLanguage,
   }, '*')
```

Because I send it directly through renderers I avoid extra code inside `main.js`, so it sends through to `myPage.js` (renderer) and receives it:

```
window.addEventListener('message', (message) => {
    if(message.data.channel == 'mainMenuUpdate') {
        // I now have args over to `iframe`
        console.log(message.data)
        //... updateColors(...) langUpdater(...)
    }
});
```

I still don't know about `myLibrary` button, but it is not caused by the `iframe` problem.